# prove that a|b and b|a iff a=+-b

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could someone tell me a simple proof to If a|b and b|a iff a=+-b.

Comment: What is your definition of $a\mid b$? Mine it that $b=ka$ for some integer $k$. How can this help you?

Comment: @strig- my definition is b=qa

Comment: So $b=q_1 a$ and $a=q_2 b$. Combine those two ... This should lead to $q_1 q_2=1$ so either $q_1=q_2=?$ or $q_1=q_2=?$.

Comment: how shall i combine it dont get it....

Comment: You can substitute the expression for $a$ from the second equation into the RHS of the first ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a|b$ and $b|a$, then

$a|b$ implies there exists a $c$ such that $b=ac$.

$b|a$ implies there exists a $c'$ such that $a=bc'$

Therefore, $a=bc'=acc'$ and so $cc'=1$. Since $c,c'\in \mathbb{Z}$ it must be the case that $c=c'=\pm 1$.

The other direction is clear; if $a=\pm b$, then there exists a $c (=\pm 1)$ such that $a=bc$ and $b=ac$ --- that is $b|a$ and $a|b$

Comment: $a=acc'$ could happen with $a=0$ while $c$ and $c'$ take any values.

Comment: Good point. Since $a|b$, we can assume $a\neq 0$. Since $0$ doesn't divide anything.

Comment: Under some definitions, everything (including $0$) divides $0$, but $0$ does not divide anything except $0$ (which is nothing)

Comment: If one of $a$ or $b$ is $0$, then both have to be and the statement is trivial. So we should assume both non-zero. Maybe I should have put this at the start of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If $b=na\wedge a=kb$ then $b\left(1-nk\right)=0$

Answer (score 1):

You can readily check that $a \mid b \implies |a| \leq |b|$. So: $$\begin{cases} |a| \leq |b| \\ |b| \leq |a|\end{cases} \implies |a|=|b| \implies a = \pm b.$$

Comment: Nice way to put that implication!

Answer (score 0):

$[a=\pm{b}]\implies$

$[a=+b]\vee[a=-b]\implies$

$([\frac{a}{b}=+1]\wedge[\frac{b}{a}=+1])\vee([\frac{a}{b}=-1]\wedge[\frac{b}{a}=-1])\implies$

$[a|b]\wedge[b|a]$

---

$[a|b]\wedge[b|a]\implies$

$\exists{m,n}\in\mathbb{Z}:[am=b]\wedge[bn=a]\implies$

$[amn=a]\implies$

$[mn=1]\implies$

$([m=+1]\wedge[n=+1])\vee([m=-1]\wedge[n=-1])\implies$

$[a=+b]\vee[a=-b]\implies$

$[a=\pm{b}]$

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here goes: $b=q_1a$ and $a=q_2b$ so
$$
b=q_1 a=q_1(q_2 b)
$$
It follows immediately that $q_1q_2=1$ so either $q_1,q_2=1$ or $q_1,q_2=-1$. The other direction is trivial, since $\pm b=\pm 1\cdot b$ so $\pm b\mid b$.

Comment: what about conversly bcoz prove has iff condition